# Permission key denied in Azure

Tags: azure, ssl, cloud, virtual-machine, gcloud-compute

I created a virtual machine on Azure. It was working fine a couple of days ago (I was able to connect to it using SSL using command prompt), after that I reserved the IP public address and shutdown the machine and . Now I am trying to connect to it via SSL using same way and it is throwing permission denied error. How to rectify this ?

*ssh -i user_key.pem username@xx.xxx.xx.xx*

> Load key "user_key.pem": Permission denied
>
> username@xx.xxx.xx.xx: Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I removed all permissions (except read by administrator) from my key.pem file. This I did because previously it was showing that the permissions are too open.

> ***Opening the command prompt as administrator mode worked.***